# Why am I getting a zero at the end and how can I do the same thing without reversing the array?

Tags: c

I am new to C, just try to understand a very tiny part of a problem I have a simple program -1 represents the end of the array :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct List list_t;
struct List {
    void * head;
    list_t * tail;
};

list_t * makelist(void * x, list_t * xs){
    list_t * ans = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    ans->head =x;
    ans->tail = xs;
    return ans;
}

list_t * makeListFromIntArray(int list[]){
    list_t * ans = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));
    int i = 0;
    while(list[i]!=-1){
        ans = makelist((void *)(intptr_t)list[i],ans);
        i++;
    }
    return ans;
}

void printList(list_t * xs){
    while(xs != NULL){
        printf("%lu\n",((intptr_t)xs->head));
        xs = xs->tail;
    }
}

int main() {
    int s[] = {1,2,3,4,5,-1};
    list_t * xs = makeListFromIntArray(s);
    printList(xs);
    return 0;
}
```

The main problem is when printList executes I am getting a zero at the end.

```
5
4
3
2
1
0

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.001 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

This is my main problem and the minor problem is the array is reversed which is understandable. I can overcome this by reversing before feeding into makelistfromintarray. However I am open more elegant solutions.

Comment: Your abuse of pointers scares me.  I understand that type punning is a thing, but that's what unions are for.

Comment: Also remove all your type-casts until your compiler comlains.

Comment: It's all part of the learning experience, but this is some crazy bad code.  You have `malloc`

Comment: Do not assume that an `int` can be stored in a `void*`. Although most of the time that's true, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: It is a part of lecture about programming languages forcing C to use closures. Ugly I guess... Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is here...

```
 list_t * ans = (list_t *) malloc(sizeof(list_t));
```

You are creating an empty node at the head of the list in `MakeListFromArray`. That line should read

```
 list_t * ans = NULL;
```

PS: [You should never cast `malloc()` in C!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565496/specifically-whats-dangerous-about-casting-the-result-of-malloc)